# How to implement a static nested class that can be modified in unity inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static, inner-classes

I'm hoping to implement a static class with nested classes which can be viewed and modified in the Unity Inspector.

Any recommendations on how to achieve this?

I've tried using nested static classes successfully, but I can't add them as a component in order to view in the inspector.

Any recommendations on how to achieve this?

Here's my example code. Without Monobehaviour I can't add it as a component to get it in the inspector.

```
using UnityEngine;

public static class Parameters
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public static class GroupA
    {
    public static float varA = 1f;
    }
    
    [System.Serializable]
    public static class GroupB
    {
    public static float varB = 2f;
    }

}
```

I can then call this with, e.g.

`Parameters.GroupA.varA;`

Thanks in advance and sorry for my code stinks.

best, Rob

Comment: Had you considered making `Parameters` a namespace, and `GroupA` and `GroupB` a MonoBehaviour with `static` properties, which are then also settable by shadowed instance-properties (like `varB_instance`) which set their static counterpart via `OnValidate()` (see [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html))? This would allow you to use `Parameters.GroupA.varA`, yet have it adjustable in inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use "Odin inspector" for such cases.

```
using UnityEngine;
using Sirenix.OdinInspector;

public static class Parameters
{
[System.Serializable]
public class GroupA
{
public float varA = 1f;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class GroupB
{
public float varB = 2f;
}

[ShowInInspector]
public static GroupA staticGroupA;
[ShowInInspector]
public static GroupB staticGroupB;

void Start()
{
GroupA = new GroupA();
GroupA.varA = 1f;
GroupB = new GroupB(); 
GroupB.varB = 2f;
}
```

I hope it helped.
Best.

Comment: Thanks Emre, I'll try this in future. I worked out a way to use singletons instead which did the job for me

Comment: Singleton is the always better way for accessing static's ^^ Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a singleton which worked second time round.
For this I added in the parent class:

```cs
public static Parameters myInstance {get; private set;}
```

and for each inner class

```cs
public GroupA groupA = new GroupA();
```

And I removed all other static references.

Comment: Welcome to your first answer in SO! If you solve your own problem without the need of others, feel free to accept your own question, instead of the other; this way you will increase the odds that others can find an useful advice and upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no third party library needed for your use case.

Instead of using `static` for this at all I would be using a [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html).

These are **assets** and therefore anything can reference them and they can store serialized values as well as implement own logic. For more information see also [Three ways to architect your game with ScriptableObjects](https://unity.com/how-to/architect-game-code-scriptable-objects)

So in your case e.g.

```
[CreateAssetMenu]
public class Parameters : ScriptableObject
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class GroupAClass
    {
        public float varA = 1f;
    }
    
    [System.Serializable]
    public class GroupBClass
    {
        public float varB = 2f;
    }

    public GroupAClass GroupA;
    public GroupBClass GroupB;
}
```

Then you create an asset via `Assets` → <kbd>right click</kbd> → <kbd>Create</kbd> → Parameters

Here you now have your values adjustable via the Inspector as usual.

And finally whenever you need access to them you have a field

```
public Parameters parameters;
```

drag in the according asset and access the values via e.g.

```
parameters.GroupA.varA
```